# Zend|Db\Sql|Expression not working in Zend SL statement

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server, angularjs, zend-framework

I cannot get valid data from the Zend Framework sql statements shown below which I use in php  and is called from an angularjs script:

```
    $where = new Where ();   
    $where->greaterThanOrEqualTo('user_id', '963');  
    $resultSet = $this->tableGateway->select(function(Select $select) use
    ($where){
    $select->where($where);  
      $select->columns(array('date_added','datemonth' => new \Zend\Db\Sql\Expression("MONTH('date_added')"), 'count' => new \Zend\Db\Sql\Expression("COUNT(*)")));
    $select->group('datemonth');
    return $resultSet;
```

My angular js script dumps the data as shown below:

```
    success(function(response) {

            for(var i in response.response) {
                var tc = response.response[i];
                alert("userdata date_added=" + tc['date_added'] + " datemonth=" + tc['datemonth'] + " count=" + tc["count"]);
         }
```

And the results are as shown:

```
userdata date_added=2014-05-22 20:00:27 datemonth=undefined count=undefined
```

Can anyone tell me if I am using the Zend\Db\Sql\Expression incorrectly or why isn't the datemonth and count not coming back correctly? I want to be able to get the number of records by month.

Update:  I was able to dump the putput from the server and it shows all the fields on the database record but none for the fields created in the Zend Expression functions for datemonth and count. Below is the dump.  Anyone know why the Expression fields aren't in the dump?

Php Code:

```
       echo "Resultset = " . $resultSet->date_added;
```

Dump of above code:

```
       Resultset = {"success":true,"response":[{"inputFilter":null,"user_id":0,"instagram_user_id":"","fbid":"","instagram_username":null, "full_name":"","profile_image":"","bio":"","website":"","media_count":0,"following_count":0,"followed_by_count":0,"like_count":0,"recommend_count":0,"date_added":"2014-05-22 20:00:27","flag_count":0,"date_updated":"","email":"","password":"","access_token":"","premium":0,"login_attempts":0,"status":0,"request_count":0,"request_date":""}]}
```

Comment: Hi, can you capture the query exactly as it being sent to SQL Server? You can capture it with SQL Server Profiler, for one. I presume you know the SQL that would return the result you need so you will immediately see how it differs from what is actually being constructed based on your code.

Comment: I am using mysql which doesn't have an sql profiler.  Does anyone know how to get an echo in php to display on my return to angular jscript so I can better analyze the server output?

Answer (score 0):

You may try this to preview your SQL query:

```
$sql = new \Zend\Db\Sql\Sql($this->tableGateway->adapter);
echo $sql->getSqlStringForSqlObject($select);
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions.  This code revealed the following sql statement:

        userData1=SELECT `user`.`date_added` AS `date_added`, MONTH('date_added') AS `datemonth`, COUNT(*) AS `count` FROM `user` WHERE `user_id` >= '963'<br />

The questions is how come it doesn't return the datemonth and count fields instead of just all the fields on the record.  In other words, return $resultSet is not the proper return to my calling program.  How do I return data from thei sql query?

Comment: `MONTH('date_added')` - use backticks instead of apostrophes